# ('invalid_client: Unauthorized', {'error': 'invalid_client', 'error_description': 'Unauthorized'}) After 7 days

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-data-api

I started a project to autocreate and upload content. This was working previously but suddenly I get an error:

```
('invalid_client: Unauthorized', {'error': 'invalid_client', 'error_description': 'Unauthorized'})
```

I've tried refreshing my secret and using a different project.
I've seen people suggest to change the project to release or something like that.

I'm using a premade google library and it always fails at:

```
cred.refresh(Request())
```

it was working for about a week and now it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.  It may be helpful if you provide enough of your code so that other members may understand the context that `cred.refresh()` is called within.

Comment: 100% thanks, so cred.refresh is using the google.auth.transport.requests library well just google but yeah it refreshes the token of the account and uses that new tokenm to create api requests